# Help understand 'cannot be dealt with through' in "The errors produced by these systems cannot be dealt with through parameter adaptation"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, passive-voice

> However, the approximation errors produced by the fuzzy logic systems, [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], can not be dealt with through parameter adaptation.

I have problem understanding this part :

> "can not be dealt with through"

thanks

Answer (score 2):

> However, the approximation errors produced by the fuzzy logic systems, [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], **can not be dealt with** through parameter adaptation.

This is a **[passive voice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice)** construction. We can remodel it into an active voice construction:

> However, one **cannot deal with** the approximation errors produced by the fuzzy logic systems, [24], [25], [26], [27], [28] through parameter adaptation.

That is, fuzzy logic systems produce approximation errors. This is a problem. You can try using parameter adaptation to solve this problem, but nothing will come out of it. Why? Because this kind of problem **cannot be dealt with** through parameter adaptation. So, you'd have to use some other method **to deal with** this problem.

Answer (score 1):

'Through' in this context means 'by' or 'by using' or 'by doing' etc. So you could say 'Weight loss cannot be achieved through eating cakes' (and we usually use 'cannot' instead of 'can not' in English, although both are correct).

Answer (score 0):

To "deal with" a problem is to do something to fix the problem. The words "deal with" can almost be thought of as a single verb.

The prepositions "by" or "through" can be used to explain the method of fixing the problem.

Example:

> We can deal with speeding cars by building small humps in the road.

The passive voice can also be used:

> Speeding cars can be dealt with by building small humps in the road.

In the above case the prepositions "with" and "by" appear next to each other, which is potentially confusing, but this confusion can be dealt with (!) by treating "dealt with" as a single verb form, whose object is "speeding cars".

If we change to a negative, we get the form you encountered:

> Speeding cars cannot be dealt with by using powerful magnets.
>
> The problems cannot be dealt with through the usual methods.